# Custom Config for Publishing to File System

Tags: visual-studio-2013, config, publish, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am having a MDHA Project and I am deploying to Devices and to the **Web**.

Is it possible (like in usual VS Projects) to have an custom Config, which calls a batch script on anything like this to publish the files on a file System?

Actually when i create a custom Config, it will also try to deploy it as an APP.

Thanks Markus

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use the same set of web assets (HTML, CSS, Javascript. etc.) to build both a hybrid app and a web site. I have a similar situation where my assets are part of an existing ASP.NET project.

I created a companion MDHA project and reused the assets by adding a target & task to the MDHA project file that *copies* the assets from the ASP.NET project to the MDHA project directory. Even though the assets are not part of the MDHA project definition (i.e., they are not present as items in the project file), this approach works because MDHA looks for files under the project directory *on disk*.

Of course, all of this depends on having web assets that are available at build-time.

Comment: Sounds good, but how do you add target and task to the MDHA project?

Comment: You have to edit the .jsproj file, which is an MS Build project file. This is going to require some familiarity with the project file schema. See [MSBuild Project File Schema Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx).